# WYVERN not showing images due to relative paths (Multi Site Manager, EE2.11.7)

Tags: assets, multi-site-manager, wyvern

I've got a secondary site using WYVERN. Everything works fine, and when I insert an image, WYVERN puts

```
/files/imagePath/image.gif
```

In the code. So the code is correct, but since I am viewing the EE control panel from the primary site's URL, the image doesn't appear within WYVERN.

Is there some setting I can change in Assets or elsewhere that will prepend *secondary-domain.com* within WYVERN so the image appears?

[EDIT]
Adding to the complexity - this site needs to run over SSL or non-SSL (allowing for visitors in China and other unfree places to access). So code output on the website needs to be relative, i.e., 
`/path/img.gif`

not

```
http://domain.com/path/img.gif
```

Comment: Did you try to prepend `{site_url}`?. So your full path in WYVERN would be `{site_url}files/imagePath/image.gif`.

Comment: If I add that in file manager setting, it gets output literally in the path _{site_url}/files/imagePath/image.gif_. Is there a place in WYVERN config to add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a trick: 
[image]

This allows the CMS to serve files over SSL or non-SSL, depending on whatever protocol is in use.